# Regex to match * at end of string

Tags: string, google-bigquery

I have various words that look like this:

big kid* jumper
kid* swing*set

I only want to replace the * when they occur at the end of a string, but not when they are in between a string. I've tried various regexes in BigQuery to no avail.

Comment: Did you mean at the end of word? I dont know how regex works in google big query but I have a ideal like this: `(?<=\w)\*(?=\B)`, that match a `*` which postitive lookbehind a word character `\w` and positive lookahead a non-word boundary (space, tab, etc) `\B`. Eg: https://regex101.com/r/xyFzcK/1

Comment: Have you tried marking the end of the string in the regexp?. /(.*)\\*$/.
^: Will represent the beggining of the string.
$: Will represent the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

This should replace only the `*` values that are at the end of a word, but *not* the `*`s that are between two words.

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE('big kid* jumper kid* swing*set', r'\*(\s|^)', '\\1') AS output
```

Example output: `big kid jumper kid swing*set`

Note: here we use a capture group to capture the following character and put it back, since [BigQuery RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) does not support Lookahead expressions.